# Locating a program in a Phing build file

Tags: phing

In a Phing build file, I would like to invoke an external program (`lessc` in this case), but the program might live in a different location depending on which system the script is run on.

This is what I am doing currently.  It works, but it smells to me:

```
<property name="lessc" value="/usr/bin/lessc" override="true" />

<if>
  <not>
    <available file="${lessc}" />
  </not>
  <then>
    <fail msg="Could not find LESS compiler at ${lessc}." />
  </then>
</if>

<exec command="${lessc} ..." />
```

I am using a `property` so that the user can specify an alternate path to `lessc` for her system, but I would prefer it if the script could automatically determine the location of the executable via e.g. `hash` or `which`.

Is this possible to do in Phing?

Comment: I have seen custom LESS task for Phing on Github if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [Use `env` on Sean Coates's blog](http://seancoates.com/blogs/use-env) the other day, which deals with a very similar problem; in his case he found that PHP scripts were failing when run via CLI on different systems because PHP was installed in different locations.

His solution was to replace the `#!/path/to/php` header with `#!/usr/bin/env php`.  Since `env` is (probably) always located at `/usr/bin/env`, the only configuration required is to ensure that the PHP binary is on the `$PATH` for whatever user is executing the CLI script.  No server-specific code changes necessary!

Well, this got me thinking.

I changed my build file to look like this, and everything is working beautifully now:

```
<property name="env" value="/usr/bin/env" override="true" />

<if>
  <not>
    <available file="${env}" />
  </not>
  <then>
    <fail msg="Unable to locate env executable at ${env}." />
  </then>
</if>

<exec command="${env} lessc ..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Smells like a custom [task](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/ExtendingPhing.html#WritingTasks) to me.

Comment: A custom task to locate the executable, or a custom task to invoke it?  I'd prefer not to port the less compiler to PHP, if that's what you're getting at!  (:

Comment: A custom task to locate (and probably auto-set) the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and ended up creating a custom condition to work like the `available` condition. It uses which / where (on Windows) to search locations in the PATH.

It's available here:
https://gist.github.com/dig412/5057536